# STORM ERROR java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: zeromq, apache-storm

Compile no problem, but after run.....

```
26183 [Thread-34] ERROR backtype.storm.util  - Async loop died!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.finalize()V
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.finalize(Native Method)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.close(ZMQ.java:339)
    at storm.starter.spout.RandomSentenceSpout.nextTuple(RandomSentenceSpout.java:56)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997$fn__4026.invoke(executor.clj:502)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:377)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
         26185 [Thread-34] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor  - 
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.finalize()V
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.finalize(Native Method)
   at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.close(ZMQ.java:339)
   at storm.starter.spout.RandomSentenceSpout.nextTuple(RandomSentenceSpout.java:56)
   at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997$fn__4026.invoke(executor.clj:502)
   at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:377)
   at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: You can elaborate more and tell when you got the error, which Storm version, local or not local Storm topology, how did you install 0MQ, which 0MQ version ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm recommends to use exactly 2.1.7 version of zeroMQ.

https://github.com/xumingming/storm-wiki/blob/master/Installing-native-dependencies.md

Other version are known to cause issues as there are some serious bugs. Which version of zeroMQ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the OP is long gone but I'm leaving this answer in case anyone else has this problem (this page had a high page rank when I googled for the same solution)

There's an issue with some versions of ZMQ (specifically the java wrapper) that throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when you try to close a socket, like storm is doing in this case.

More info here:

https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/237

The obvious solution would be to upgrade your jzmq version (or in this case, storm version).

Cheers.