# jzmq vs jeromq for getting ZeroMQ up and running, jeromq works but not jzmq, but WHY?

Tags: java, centos, zeromq, centos6

It took me a day to solve this point so maybe it saves your time in case you are planning on setting up a CentOS 6.4 with ZeroMQ and java binding.

Installed jzmq, libzmq, zmq-4.x from the source from github for the basic hello world example. Still kept getting what almost drove me crazy:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit()V
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit(Native Method)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:435)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.socket(ZMQ.java:365)
at samples.zeromq.HWClient.main(HWClient.java:15)
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzmq</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But before giving up completely(!) I changed it to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jeromq</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And everything was solved!

I suppose something is wrong with the JINI wrapping of jzmq. Any ideas why this happens? And potentially how to solve it?

Comment: @Reimeus the possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474624/storm-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror) is to do with storm and for version 2.1.7. The exception is related to method finalize not nativeInit!

Comment: Have you added the jzmq native lib to the Java library path? "java -Djava.library.path=[jzmq.path] ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Claude mentioned, libzmq might not be on the library path.

A solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230738/installing-zmq-module-on-redhat-linux-rhel-6-2-64bit-machine/21237417#21237417).